# A program that inputs a year and displays “Leap year "if it is leap year or "Not leap year" if it is not leap year without using the modulus symbol

Tags: turbo-c++, turbo-c

So far I've come up with this however it doesn't seem to output results consistently.

```
if (year/4*4==year)
{
cout<<"It is a leap year!";
}
else
{
cout<<"It is not a leap year!";
}
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: I don't know turbo-C/C++ but if standard math rules still hold won't that always be true? | lets say year is 1 if (1 / 4) * 4 equals 1 or if 0.25 * 4 equals 1

Comment: leap year has some basic concept, 1--- it should be divisible by 4 or 400, but if its divisible by 100, then it must be divisible by 400......code according to this concept

Comment: @AndrewBone is there a formula on how i can check if a number is divisible by 4?

Comment: @aspiringprogrammer as I say I'm just going by guess work but something like floor(year/4)*4==year might do it, I'm not sure if floor exists in C though. Worth a shot I guess.

Comment: @AndrewBone what is floor ?

Comment: @aspiringprogrammer round down to the closest integer so back to our example from before | floor(1 / 4)*4 | floor(0.25)*4 | 0*4 | 0 != 1|

Comment: @aspiringprogrammer `if ( year % 4 == 0 )` to check if year (an integer, I guess) is divisible by 4

Comment: @AndrewBone in C, if both operands of a division are integer, an integer division is performed. So 1/4 gives 0. 1%4 gives the reminder: 1

Comment: it still outputs incorrectly.

Comment: Can you please show us Your inputs and outputs?

Comment: if ( floor(year/4)*year==year) still gives the same output as if(year/4*4==year)
like when i put 1991, it says that it is a leap year when it is not.

Comment: How exactly do you declare `year`? [Here](https://ideone.com/J0cjJ9) you can see that if year is an int your code should work, at least the divisible by 4 part, finding a leap year is [a bit more complicated](https://ideone.com/JUUo62).

Comment: yup i declared it as int still does not work.

Comment: @Bob__ i tried this https://ideone.com/J0cjJ9 and it works! now the problem is how do i modify this for loop ? so that the output will depend on the users input?

Comment: How do you do that in your code? That's probably where the error come from. Are you checking the user input?

Comment: @Bob__
int year;
cin>>year;

now what do i do with the for loop part?

Comment: like [here](https://ideone.com/wkHDNM)...

Comment: @Bob__ i see thank you so much! how about if the user just wants to input one particular year?

Comment: int year; cin>>year; instead of the loop... Does it works or not with your compiler? Have you tryed to compile the snippets of the links in your environment?

Comment: yes int year;cin year; does work in my compiler and everything you've sent has worked so far. My question is how to modify that for loop ? So when a user enter "1992" it'll just output "It is a leap year?". Thank you for all your help so far, i am truly grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if some years entered by the user are leap years or not, you just have to write a loop.

In my code I also added an helper function (Turbo C++ has bool type, right? It's part of the standard...) with the exact formula (you can find that online). Note that the loop ends when the user inputs something that is not an integer (or EOF).

```
#include <iostream>

bool is_leap( int y )
{
    return  y % 400 == 0  ||  ( y % 100 != 0  &&  y % 4 == 0 );
}

int main()
{
    int year;

    while ( std::cin >> year )
    {
        if ( is_leap(year) )
        {
            std::cout << year << " is a leap year!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << year << " is not a leap year.\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For example, you can try:

```
1857 is not a leap year.
1900 is not a leap year.
1980 is a leap year!
1991 is not a leap year.
2000 is a leap year!
2016 is a leap year!
```